# Error in subset.default. Object not found

Tags: r

I am learning R in class and I am working on a project and have run into an error that I can't seem to figure out.

I am trying to create a subset in a regression but keep getting the error:

```
Error in subset.default(df, ethnicity == "Black") : 
  object 'ethnicity' not found
```

This is the line of code I am using to try to create the regression.

```
reg3 <- lm(highgrade_comp ~ ethnicity + highgrade_bio_dad + female, data=subset(df,ethnicity=="Black"))
```

And I am not sure why it is not working because I have created an object called "ethnicity" and it runs when I print out a table and it also shows up in my data said as a new variable.

```
table(nlsy$ethnicity)

Output: 
  Black Hispanic    Other    White 
    2335     1901       83     4665
```

This is the code that I am using to create the regression/where I am attempting to make a subset.

```
nlsy$ethnicity <- as.factor(ifelse(nlsy$race_ethnicity=="Black", "Black",
  ifelse(nlsy$race_ethnicity=="Hispanic", "Hispanic",
  ifelse(nlsy$race_ethnicity=="Non-Black / Non-Hispanic" | nlsy$race_ethnicity=="White", "White", "Other"))))
```

I changed df to nlsy and get a new error.

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Comment: Use `subset` for data.frames

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry I am new to r what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but shouldn't the first argument to `subset` be `nlsy`, not `df`?

Comment: Simply use your command as it is right now, but leave out the .default, like so: `subset(df, ethnicity == "Black")`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks Andre, that works. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

If the only `ethnicity` in your subsetted `data.frame` is `black`, then you don't need the variable `ethnicity` as a predictor.

What you have with ethnicity, and what to try without ethnicity:

```
reg3 <- lm(highgrade_comp ~ ethnicity + highgrade_bio_dad + female, data=subset(nlsy,ethnicity=="Black"))
reg3 <- lm(highgrade_comp ~             highgrade_bio_dad + female, data=subset(nlsy,ethnicity=="Black"))
```